# getting another column is one column of data has maximum value in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame

```
date    object   price
190403    a        1
190405    a       23
190506    b       -4
190507    d       56
```

I want to get a date of a column having a maximum Price i.e 190507

**expected output**
190507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scalar output, always one max date value use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) with convert `date` to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df.set_index('date')['price'].idxmax()
```

If want all max values in `Series` use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and compare all values by `max`, [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is fir also filtering `date` column:

```
df.loc[df['price'].eq(df['price'].max()), 'date']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subset the `df` so that you only have the row where the `price` column is at its maximum, and then choose the `date` column:

```
df[df.price==df.price.max()].date
```